# Чат бот телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать чат бот в телеге, и нужно под постом сделать кнопку, что она бы отображала пользователей,  которые на неё нажали(типо как лайк)
Реально ли это сделать, или может какие-то альтернативные варианты есть?
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вся интересующая информация есть тут:
https://core.telegram.org/

Смотря какую информацию вы хотите выводить (я так понимаю на сайте).
Если количество пользователей, да это без проблем.

А вот на счет имён и аватаров, не уверен, будет ли это нарушать конфиденциальность.

Comment: Именно в чате. Бот для поиска попуток. Допустим, когда бот запускается, появляется две кнопки «Предложить поездку» и «Найти поездку», если пользователь нажал на «Предложить..» то он должен ввести какую-то инфу о своей поездке и отправить их в БД, а если пользователь нажал «Найти..» , то он тоже должен ввести инфу которую ищет, а потом бот выводит инфу о тех поездках которые предложили пользователи. Реально сделать???? Спасибо!

Comment: А потом когда найденны какие-то результаты предложенных поездок, нужно что-то придумать с бронировкой места. За это и спрашивал, можно ли под постом кнопку сделать чтобы при нажатии можно было забронировать себе место.